# Reformatting response data in react.js setState method

Tags: reactjs

im recently trying to convert a Vue project to a React project . Here is a problem that im facing.

I have a data that comes in the format of :

```
0:
iteration: -1
    state:
        description: null
        id: 1
        label: "Start"
        slug: "start"
```

I wish to do a save this into my component state but in a different format :

```
0:
iteration: -1
description: null
id: 1
label: "Start"
slug: "start"
```

The reason for doing this is to be able to get the `id`of the object by calling response.data.id , instead of response.data.state.id

Answer (score 1):

You can map over the data and reformat it by returning the desired object from it

```
const newData = data.map(item => ({
   iteration: item.iteration,
   ...item.state
}));
```

Now newData will have the format you want. If you have more keys within item that you want to have in the data, you can make modifications in the above returned object

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply , it works , i will upvote this when the system allows me

Comment: Happy to have helped :-)